QT Creator CMAKE When I build a release for my application, it says that "The code execution cannot proceed because libunwind.dll was not found"
I am using QT Creator version 6 and CMAKE.
When I build the release application and then try to run the .exe, it pops up these two errors:


My PATH variable is: C:\Qt\6.7.1\mingw_64\bin
After manually adding the two files taken from C:\Qt\6.7.1\llvm-mingw_64\bin (libunwind.dll and libc++.dll) it gives another error.
Error:

